# IOS/Storboard: Is it Safe to Copy and Paste View Controller within One Storyboard with Autolayout

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a view controller in storyboard with a lot of elements and autlayout constraints that also has segues from another VC and I need to make a similar VC.

Is it safe to copy and paste a VC to create a duplicate?  I would cut and past from the navigator pane, not the actual storyboard.

The VC in question is wired to a class.  The cloned VC will get its own class and I don't mind deleting the connections.  I just don't want to mess up storyboard.

When I was first experimenting with Storyboard, I tried this a couple times and it seemed to corrupt early projects so I'm wary.  Are there any safeguards that should be taken first?

Thanks in advance for any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is, You can copy paste it in same StoryBoard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally feasible to copy ViewController.  Actually instead of copying VC, you are copying and paste scene.

In the following , I paster a bunch of tableviewController scene from the top scene. 
[image]

After copy/paste, the new scenes are completely independent of each other even with the original tableviewController scene.

If you need to change to other customized vc, just change the name here. Now the new scene is configured to your own new vc class and again has nothing to do with the original vc.

[image]

One thing needs to remember: if your original vc has storyboard identifier, you may need to change after copy/paste.

If you have too many identifies, you may consider to paste the scene to another storyboard. Then you can use an reference storyboard to help you connect.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES from the navigator pane or the canvas and Autolayout constraints will be preserved in your cloned VC.

When you select your cloned VC in Interface Builder, you can edit it's custom class in the Identity inspector.

If your cloned VC as a different class, you should definitely clean up the outlet connections and the IBActions.